# Python SQL query large data

Tags: python, sql

I need help with a extraction to make a report, usually this report is weekly.

Query example:

```
    select * from table1  
inner join table2 on table1.id_sinistro = table2.sinistro__id_sinistro  
inner join table3 on table1.id_sinistro = table3.id_sinistro 
where table3.created_at >= '2021-01-01' and table1.created_at >= '2021-01-01'
```

The query does not matter, its just a example where I am getting from 3 large tables with a date condition.

But, I guess its not efficient execute the query every time I'll extract the data to make the report. Before my query took an hour, but now, the script just die.

To automatize this report, I extract with Pandas and make a pdf from the script.

```
import pandas as pd 
import sqlalchemy
import time
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import os
load_dotenv()

engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('mysql+pymysql://"url":3306/database')

main_query = """select * from table1  
inner join table2 on table1.id_sinistro = table2.sinistro__id_sinistro  
inner join table3 on table1.id_sinistro = table3.id_sinistro 
where table3.created_at >= '2021-01-01' and table1.created_at >= '2021-01-01'"""

now = time.time()
df = pd.read_sql_query(main_query,engine)
print('Execution time: {} seconds'.format(time.time() - now))
```

I Want know the best idea/practice to do this job, how can I store the data and extract new data every week or every time I run the script.

Answer (score 0):

- Name the columns in the select and only fetch the columns that you need.
- Check that you have indexes on the columns used in the joins and the where. Ideally the columns used in the join will be primary keys and foreign keys.

```
SHOW INDEX FROM table_name;
SHOW CREATE TABLE table_name;
```

and as needed

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD PRIMARY KEY (column_name);
ALTER TABLE table_name
     ADD CONSTRAINT fk_table_col_otable_ocol 
     FOREIGN KEY this_column 
     REFERENCES other_table_name(other_column);
CREATE  INDEX table_name_column ON table_name(column_name;
```

- Create a view, this allows MySQL to optimise the query and cache results.

```
CREATE VIEW view_name AS
SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE ... ;
```